# Erro ao exportar footer no ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, react, npm

Ao rodar o comando npm start retorna o erro abaixo no terminal, estou importando o arquivo `/components/footer/Footer.js` no arquivo `/src/index.js`

> **//ERRO**
>   Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/components/register/Register.js
>   Attempted import error: 'Footer' is not exported from '../footer/Footer'

```
//Footer.js

import React from "react";

export default class Footer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <footer className="footer">
      <div>
        <p> Snef Brasil </p>
      </div>
    </footer>
    );
  };
}
```

---

```
//index.js

import React  from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import App from './components/app/App'
import {Footer} from './components/footer/Footer'
import {Header} from './components/header/Header'


ReactDOM.render(
   <App />,
   <Footer />,
   <Header />,
   document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: Só isso não tem como responder

Comment: Vou editar com mais detalhes

Comment: @VirgilioNovic acabei de editar, está melhor?

Comment: O problema parece estar no ReactDOM.render, você tem vários vários componentes, o que precisaria é ter uma div e agrupar todos dentro dela, veja esta resposta, ela pode te ajudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41690545/render-multiple-components-by-reactdom

Comment: Sim você está importando errado não precisa das Chaves nesse caso e também precisar um root do componente mestre e chamar os componentes dentro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu código agora disponibilizado na pergunta fica fácil detectar os problemas, na importação, tem as chaves, mas, está fazendo a importação do próprio arquivo, então edite da seguinte forma:

```
import Footer from './components/footer/Footer'
import Header from './components/header/Header'
```

e vai resolver essa primeira pendencia de problemas do seu código.

Outro fator é que você precisa ter uma componente `root` envolvendo esses outros componentes a maneira tradicional é criar um componente e dentro desse componente importar os outros componentes, dessa forma atual fica meio inviável porque o código por ir crescendo e o número de componentes também, então faça um componente que vai ter esses outros dentro.

***Exemplo:***

```
//index.js

import React  from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import Root from './components/root/Root'
ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

dentro desse componente `Root` faça:

```
//Root.js

import React from "react";
import App from './components/app/App'
import Footer from './components/footer/Footer'
import Header from './components/header/Header'

export default class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <App />
          <Header />
          <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

Essa é uma das formas, mas, existem várias formas e vários tipos de organização, o problema é que acabou importando errado, aquela forma de importar deveria ter um `index.js` na raiz dos componentes e dentro as importações, mas, aumenta a complexidade se não souber organizar.

Não sei qual editor está usando, mas, [o Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) com [essas extensões para import](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=auto%20import&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance), vai ajudar a codificar o seu código e importar corretamente seus componentes.

Answer (score 0):

Note no seu arquivo `Footer.js` que você está exportando o componente como `default`:

> ```
> export default class Footer extends React.Component { /* ... */ }
> //     ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
> // Notação de um default export
> ```

E no `index.js`, você está importanto usando a notação de um *named export*:

> ```
> import { Footer } from './components/footer/Footer';
> //     ↑        ↑
> // Notação de um named import
> ```

Para importar um módulo que você exportou como `default`, você deve deixar a notação de um *named export* (remover as chaves):

Ficará então com:

```js
import Footer from './components/footer/Footer';
```

É por isso que na maioria das vezes procuro sempre me manter a um padrão: ou só uso *named exports* ou só *default exports*. Fica por você escolher qual abordagem é mais vantajosa.

Para saber mais, leia sobre [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) e [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

---

Vale citar ainda que você não pode renderizar múltiplos elementos como você está fazendo:

> ```
> ReactDOM.render(
>    <App />,      // ┐
>    <Footer />,   // ┼─ Não é encorajado pelo React e leva à erros.
>    <Header />,   // ┘
>    document.getElementById('root'));
> ```

Precisa renderizar um único componente, que pode ter outros sub-componentes. Nesse caso, é ideal que você use um [`Fragment`](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.Fragment>
    <App />
    <Footer />
    <Header />
  </React.Fragment>
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```